# Xpath in R - Invalid predicate

Tags: r, xpath

I'm struggling with an `Xpath` formula. I want to capture a product name and have tried lots of versions only to get:

```
Invalid predicate 1206
```

or:

```
Invalid predicate 1207
```

or:

```
character(0)
```

The structure I'm after is:

```
<div class="product__info">
 :: before
    <a href="/our-range/brands/a/acme" itemprop="brand" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
            <img itemprop="logo" class="brand"     src="https://picture.png" ></a>
       <h1 itemprop="name" class="fn">Acme Whizz</h1>
```

I have tried:

```
xpath = ".fn"

xpath = ".product__info"

xpath = "//div[@class=product__info]/text()"
```

(amongst many others.)

Where am I going wrong with this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand very well what do you want to find, so here are some xpathes almost for everything in your code.
You can access your `div` with this xpath:

```
//div[@class="product__info"]
```

You can find image that has `logo` like this:

```
//img[@itemprop="logo"]
```

Or the `brand` like so:

```
//a[@itemprop="brand"]
```